# Filesystem space available using SNMP

Tags: linux, solaris, snmp, filesystems

I'd like to collect filesystem space information using SNMP on Solaris 10 and Ubuntu 11.10. The problem is that SNMP doesn't seem to have an attribute that corresponds to the "Available" column in `df`.

For example, here is the `df -k` output of my local filesystem:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1             36841040  13489312  21480268  39% /
```

And here are the relevant attributes from the SNMP daemon (as per [the Net-SNMP documentation](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/host.html#hrStorageTable)):

```
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.31 = STRING: /
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.31 = INTEGER: 9210260
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.31 = INTEGER: 3372328
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.31 = INTEGER: 4096 Bytes
```

Now `9210260*4 = 36841040`, and `3372328*4 = 13489312`, which match the columns in the `df` output. However, I can't see any attribute that corresponds to the "Available" column. Note that it's not just a matter of subtracting the two columns - the "Available" column seems to take into account some hidden overheads which vary per filesystem.

Is there a way to collect or calculate the "Available" column information using SNMP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do additional configuration on top of standard SNMP to get available space.  The [NET-SNMP documentation](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/mrtg/index.html) mentions the following:

> There are two tables that can be used when monitoring disk space,
>   UCD-SNMP-MIB:dskTable and HOST-RESOURCES-MIB:hrStorageTable. There are
>   two noticeable differences bwtween these tables: UCD-SNMP-MIB:dskTable
>   requires a configuration directive in snmpd.conf, but it also gives a
>   direct measure of the percentage of free space

So sounds like you just need to use UCD-SNMP-MIB instead of HOST-RESOURCES-MIB to get to dskTable instead of hrStorageTable.